# Spot the error in this invalid argument

Tags: logic

The following argument is invalid and has an error. I guess it is in the line where he has taken there exists $p(y,y)$ because there is $y$ in $S$. But I have no idea how to explain it. Any help?

Assume that  $\forall x \in S , \exists y \in S, p(x,y)$

$$ \text{Let } y \in S,
\exists y \in S p(y,y)$$

$$ \exists y \in S, p(y,y)$$
$$ \forall x \in S, \exists y \in S, p(x,y) \implies \exists y \in S, p(y,y) $$

Comment: I think this step from $Let y \in S$,$\exists y \in S p(y,y)$ is faulty in the sense that both the $y$s are supposed to be different, whereas here both are same. For eg. if p(a,b) then this line claims p(b,b) or p(a,a) about which we know nothing.

Comment: Well @tpb261: it is not that both y's "are supposed to be different" but rather that they're not forced to be one and the same...

Comment: @DonAntonio True. I had wrong wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the very first step in your "proof", you have applied the following logical law :

> $\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha[t/x]$, where $t$ is *substitutable* for $x$ in $\alpha$.

The proviso regarding *substitutability* is intended exactly in order to avoid errors like yours: in using $y$ as *term* $t$ in the "instantiation" of the universal quantifier $\forall x$, the term $y$ has been "captured" by the quantifier $\exists y$, altering the meaning of the formula.

We have to use a *substitutable* term [i.e.one which does not conflict with the existsing quantifiers], like a new variable $v$, to get :

> $∃yp(v,y)$;

but then we cannot assume that the "object" which the existential quantifier asserts to exist is the "same" object referenced by $v$; thus, you can only conclude with :

> $p(v,w)$

which cannot give us : $\exists yp(y,y)$.

For a counterexample showing the fallacy of $\forall x \exists y P(x,y) \rightarrow \exists y P(y,y)$ consider as $P$ the "less than" relation ($<$) in the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers*.

We have that $\exists y(n < y)$, for all $n \in \mathbb N$ (it is enough to pick $n+1$ as value for $y$) but it is **not** true that : $n < n$, for some $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The first line says "once you pick an $x$ in $S$, there is forced to be a $y$ in $S$ such that $p(x,y)$ is true."

The second line says "having picked $y$ in $S$, $p(y,y)$ is true."  This does not follow from the first line.  It makes the error of conflating the bound variable "y" at the beginning of the second line with the unbound formal parameter "y" in the expression "$p(x,y)$" in the first line.  The first line may also be written $\forall x \in S, \exists z \in S \ \text{such that} \ p(x,z)$ and then the conflation cannot be made since the symbol "y" no longer appears in the line.  Then when, in the second line, the specialization "$x$"$\rightarrow$"$y$" is made there is no other "$y$" present.